# How to fix this storage issue?

Tags: 22.04, vmware, disk-usage

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 in VMware. It has 685 GB of disk space out of which 620 GB is free, but in the host machine the Ubuntu folder is  900 GB covering my whole NVMe SSD. How can I clean it up?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From your screenshots, we can only guess, but maybe you have a fixed-size vm disk and want a dynamic one. You can use `VBoxManage clonemedium` with option `--variant Standard` to change that.